# why does my twitter OAuth keep on asking Allow or Deny

Tags: api, twitter

I already clicked allow, but it keep on asking me to Allow or deny.
What could be the problem?

And I check on my twitter settings > connections
my application is not listed in there...

I'm using this guy's library http://www.haughin.com/code/twitter/

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to change the authorizeUrl from Twitter.php library from haughin. The code looks like this:

```
protected $authorizeUrl = 'http://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same library and my applications is listed in settings but... it keep on asking allow or denay as well. Maybe is an error in the library?